# Using Jmeter recording, can't able to getting network connetion in moziilla firefox. But it's working fine in internet explorer.

Tags: firefox, networking, jmeter, performance-testing, mozilla

[Error shown in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fl0q.png) while recording the jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` certificate in JMeter's "lib" folder. If it is there - install it into your browser, check out [Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for detailed instructions.

If it is not there - check *jmeter.log* for anything suspicious. Most likely you're using old Java and/or JMeter version. Try upgrading to:

- JMeter 3.0
- [Java SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) or [Server JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html) version 8

If nothing helps - try an alternative solutions i.e. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)